# Accidentally edited a windows header, now nothing compiles

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I was writing a program that used the windows midi interface, and at some point I was following the definition of a symbol and ended up in one of the windows headers. I must have accidentally edited it before closing it because now when I try to compile my code, I get literally hundreds of errors like:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LPUINT" is undefined    MidiUtils   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\joystickapi.h    395 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "DRVCALLBACK" is undefined   MidiUtils   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\mmeapi.h 49  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "LPMMTIME" is undefined  MidiUtils   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\mmeapi.h 510 
... plus 162 more errors
```

I'm not sure what file specifically I messed up, or what I did to mess it up. Is there a way to revert the standard windows headers back to what they should be?

Edit:

After following a suggestion in the comments, I looked through the folders that contain the header files to see which if any had been modified recently, and it appears that none have. I'm not sure where to go from here. If it's an issue with my project, I'm not sure what it might be, as even reverting to an earlier revision still encounters the error.

Comment: Have a look for a recently edited header file? From the file browser: sort by date modified.

Comment: Didn't your IDE/editor warn you about closing a modified file?

Comment: If you didn't have UAC disabled you wouldn't have been able to do this.

Comment: @WeatherVane - In retrospect, that seems obvious. Searching through the folders now though, it looks like nothing has been modified, so I'm even more mystified as to what the error might be stemming from. :-/

Comment: @remyLebeau I would think so, but also I have a very rambunctious toddler crawling over me while I'm coding here so I figured some errant keys might have gotten hit while the file was open. Looking at what files have been recently modified though, I'm not sure that that was the case.

Comment: @Alex did you check the modified timestamp of your source files? Maybe an `#include` got deleted?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looking at the timestamps wouldn't be very informative, because they've all been recently edited. However, I did find the issue. The order of the header files "mmsyscom.h" and "windows.h" got flipped by my code formatter, which turns out to cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after digging some more. I had

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "mmsyscom.h"
```

In a header file, and after my code formatter ran it swapped their order so that they were alphabetical. Turns out `mmsyscom.h` relies on a bunch of definitions in `windows.h` which was the source of the issue. I'm not sure why I saw continued to see the error when I reverted to a previous commit - maybe I just didn't go back far enough. Either way, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there a way to revert the standard windows headers?

A: Yes.  Restore from backup, or reinstall your SDK.

It sounds like you probably don't take backups ;)

If you got the SDK from Visual Studio, one option might be to simply reinstall MSVS.

The files you mention, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include`, are part of the Windows 10 SDK.  It's installed when you install MSVS.  You can also download it separately from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/